# Average of an Active Record of an active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, So I'm working on a book review site. 
I am wanting to show the average rating of all the books by a certian author. This is what I have currently and it works but there has to be a better way.

`<% @author.books.each { |book| book.reviews.each { |review| x = x + review}} %>

<% @author.books.each { |book| book.reviews.each { |review| y = y +1}} %>

<%= x/y %>`

I can do 
`<% @book.reviews.average(:ratings) %>`

but there has to be a more elegant option that would work similar to

> `<% @author.books.reviews.average(:ratings) %>`

Sadly the above command does not work even though
`<% @author.books.count %>` does.

Using Ruby 1.9.2p290 and rails 3.2.8
Thank you so much for any help you can offer.

*edited*
Adding my updated class files after first answer.
author.rb

> `class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
>
>     attr_accessible :a1stname, :asurname
>
>     has_many :books
>
>     has_many :reviews :through => :books
>
>     def afull_name
>
>       "#{asurname}, #{a1stname}"
>
>     end
>
>   end`

book.rb

> `class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
>
>     attr_accessible :author_id, :description, :title
>
>     belongs_to :author
>
>     has_many :reviews
>
>     validates :author_id, presence: true
>
>     end`

Now when I call @author or Author.find I get

```
syntax error, unexpected ":", expecting keyword_end
          has_many :reviews :through => :books 
                             ^
```

Comment: Tried .joins but got an undefined method 'joins'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the relationship is

```
author has_many :books 
book has_many :reviews
```

add

```
author has_many :reviews :through => :books #uses a inner join
```

which can be used as

```
author.reviews.average(:ratings)
```

Comment: unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end has_many :reviews :*through => :books

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need but it isn't working I've read several explanations on the :through and it is written properly. I have posted my models files in the original question.

Comment: I'm an idiot! forgot the , after the :reviews Please update your answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterBlomgren i just wanted to tell that u can use 'through' for ur solving ur problem. the above code is psuedo.

Comment: yeah I did use this the code was missing a "," That is what I meant by "update your answer." Mostly to help anyone who stumbles across this answer. The correct answer is author has_many :reviews, :through => :books. I appreciate your help. the question it self is pseudo ;-D